# Terminal & Git on Android Mobile

Tags: android, python, git, terminal

**This is not a duplicate question as my previous question is deleted.**

I use terminal to run my Python and MongoDB codes and willing to use Git to do push/pull my codes into a remote repository. Just wanted to know if I can install a real working terminal in my Android Lolly Pop Phone which will allow me to install Git using...

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

Type command. If it is not possible then can anyone tell me whether I can use Git on my Android phone via terminal in any way?

Comment: Previous question is deleted.

Comment: Only if you know how to root your phone and/or you know how to cross-compile C code from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be best off just using one of the several apps on the market, [SGit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.sheimi.sgit&hl=en) was the first that came up for me in a search.

I don't expect you'd have much luck trying to use git directly in a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `termux` on android.
Follow the procedures:

```
$ apt update 
$ apt upgrade
$ pkg install git 
$ git clone <repository address >
```

To set up storage:

```
$ termux-setup-storage
```